# Printing number pairs (two numbers) in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get used to the new formatting options in python-3.

Is there simpler way of printing sequence of number pairs (two numbers) in python3 ?

```
for x in range(0,n): # [0, n-1]
    print("{} {}".format(x, x*x));
```

If this is the shortest and simplest way, please, could you ensure me?

P.S. I am asking about "new" formatting options, due to the fact [Old String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting-operations) has become "The formatting operations described here are obsolete and may go away in future versions of Python.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for x in range(0,n):
    print(x, x*x)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I could miss that ;).

Comment: The space between `print` and parentheses is very misleading.

Comment: @eudoxos: This looked so much like print statement and a tuple from Python 2, not a print function from Python 3